# How to suppress missing rows in a pivottable drill down action

Tags: web, iccube

Is it possible in icCube version 5.0.2 to have a **navigation strategy** that drills-down to its children, but only shows children with data (so a NON EMPTY).

I managed to get this working in the previous versin 4.8 using custom MDX but the MDX syntax has changed and my solution does not work anymore!.

Enclosed a picture on the live demo dashboard called "pivottable" indicating what I would like to achieve.

[embedded picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBupv.png)

If I verify the MDX that is generated I see a new custom MDX syntax, like:

```
axis 0 {....}
axis 1 {drill down parent MDX statement}
```

The text between curly brackets is the drilldown MDX statement.
What I want to achieve, MDX-wise, is a NON EMPTY in front of the statement, e.g.:

```
axis 1 NON EMPTY {drill down parent MDX statement}
```

Any suggestion how to achieve this is welcomed.

This example can be found [here](http://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3reportName=Pivot%20Table)

Comment: Also in version 5.1 it looks as if it does not work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved in 5.1. I was not looking in the right direction.

To enforce a non empty drilldown on children do the following:

- open the widget
- select the tab Navigation
- select drilldown strategy mdxExpression
- and for the MDX expression type: non empty $member.children

And voila, you only see the rows with data

Checking the generated MDX shows:

```
SELECT
... ON COLUMNS
... ON ROWS
 FROM ...
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
axis 0 ...
axis 1 NON EMPTY  ...
```